# How to safely shutdown/reboot a Windows PE environment?

Tags: windows, windows-pe

I read http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744537(WS.10).aspx and made a WinPE iso myself. It boots OK and I do something about diskpart, imagex and bcdboot, screen shot below:

[image]

But I have a question, how to safely shutdown/reboot the WinPE environment so that all buffered data is flushed to disk.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I got it. In winpe.chm provided by Windows AIK. It says:

```
wpeutil shutdown

wpeutil reboot
```

Tried it, true.

[image]